# Ubuntu 12.04 install stalls with black screen

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I'm trying to install 12.04 from an install CD.  I get to the initial screen asking if I want to try ubuntu, install ubuntu, or check the disc.  If I choose install the screen goes black and that's it.  The CD spins for a few minutes and then stops and nothing else happens.  Any thoughts?

z75,
core i5 3550,
nvidia geforce gtx 550ti

Comment: Have you tried burning another CD?

Comment: Yes, twice actually.  After choosing the proper combination of internet search terms I discovered a workaround.  Had to edit the text in grub replacing "quiet" with "noquiet", "splash" with "nosplash", and adding "nomodeset".  Also had to enable the integrated graphics in bios.  Now there is a new problem in that I can't boot into Linux.  There is not even an option to do so upon restarting.

Comment: Which type of installation are you choosing?

Comment: I chose the first option to install it along with windows.